# Tour library for NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Is there a tour library available for NativeScript? I have seen such libraries for javascript like [Crumble](http://blog.tommoor.com/crumble/) however, I believe it does not work for NativeScript due to its non-DOM environment. I'm looking for a library that could highlight some parts of my app (perhaps like a chat bubble) to tour the user around my mobile app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a plugin called nativescript-coachmarks that seems to do what you're looking for: https://github.com/nathanwalker/nativescript-coachmarks

Good luck!

Comment: looks great! thank you!